# Why is PowerShell taking so long?

Tags: powershell

Anything I do in PowerShell seems to take forever.

```
P> Measure-Command -Expression {Write-Output "hi"}


Days              : 0
Hours             : 0
Minutes           : 0
Seconds           : 12
Milliseconds      : 513
Ticks             : 125130193
TotalDays         : 0.000144826612268519
TotalHours        : 0.00347583869444444
TotalMinutes      : 0.208550321666667
TotalSeconds      : 12.5130193
TotalMilliseconds : 12513.0193
```

I checked my $profile, and it`s empty. But it sure takes a long time for PowerShell to tell me where my profile is:

```
PS F:\> Measure-Command -Expression {$profile}


Days              : 0
Hours             : 0
Minutes           : 0
Seconds           : 12
Milliseconds      : 398
Ticks             : 123980891
TotalDays         : 0.00014349640162037
TotalHours        : 0.00344391363888889
TotalMinutes      : 0.206634818333333
TotalSeconds      : 12.3980891
TotalMilliseconds : 12398.0891
```

What could be the problem?  I'm working with PowerShell 5:

```
PS F:\> get-host | select-object version

Version
-------
5.1.18362.1801


PS F:\>
```

But that also takes 12 seconds to compute:

```
PS F:\> measure-command { get-host | select-object version }


Days              : 0
Hours             : 0
Minutes           : 0
Seconds           : 12
Milliseconds      : 442
Ticks             : 124426798
TotalDays         : 0.000144012497685185
TotalHours        : 0.00345629994444444
TotalMinutes      : 0.207377996666667
TotalSeconds      : 12.4426798
TotalMilliseconds : 12442.6798
```

Comment: It's a corporate environment, and we do have Mcafee.  What's a good way to find out what`s going on?

Comment: If nothing else is slow, I would look out for antivirus-style software causing issues. It's strange that all your examples take 12 seconds, maybe mcafee is timing out trying to check some network resource before allowing powershell to continue?

Comment: I have this problem on one of my servers (only that one, no others; and not on any desktops).  The delay is 17 seconds, not 12. And it only happens with the `cls` command. What could possibly be going on?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe that it's because of the antivirus software. It might be loading some antivirus related modules before the PowerShell module. One way to confirm this is by running the following command in cmd.

```
powershell.exe -c "Write-Host $PID;Start-Sleep -s 30"
```

This will print the PID associated with the PowerShell process and sleep for 30 seconds, Meantime open another PowerShell session and run

```
Get-Process | where {$_.Id -eq <PASTE_YOUR_PID>} | select -ExpandProperty modules
```

This will [list the modules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.modules?view=net-5.0#System_Diagnostics_Process_Modules) that have been loaded by the PowerShell process. If you are seeing your antivirus related DLLs in the list, most likely that causing the slow down.

Comment: Is it normal for that second command to yield 125 results?

Comment: @pabrams No. It depends upon the PowerShell snippet(In this case it is `"Write-Host $PID;Start-Sleep -s 30"`) you are running.

Comment: So there's obviously something very wrong?  I guess I'll throw a ticket in the corporate help desk bucket...

Comment: Did you see any Mcafee related DLL with in the list?

Comment: Yes, but not as many as I expected.  I'll post a list in a moment filtered by mcafee

Comment: So, I dunno, I got some corporate security to reinstall some stuff, and the problem went away.

Comment: I saw only `C:\Program Files\McAfee\WPS\1.11.279.1\mc-sec-plugin-x64.dll`.
I opened the McAfee LifeSave, clicked on `∷` on the left bar, opened the `Real-Time scanning` settings and pressed `Turn off`. Then Powershell immmediately became much faster.